# Calibration of Realsense R200 camera

Tags: ros, realsense-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, I would like to ask is it possible to calibrate the infrared (IR) camera for the realsense r200 camera as I am using the camera to detect obstacle through the use of disparity map.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246272/calibration-of-realsense-r200-camera/) by [timku](https://answers.ros.org/users/28140/timku/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-10-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlexandreB](https://answers.ros.org/users/25418/alexandreb/) on 2016-10-24**:
The driver already gives you a depth image, wouldn't it be better just to convert the pointcloud to a disparity image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The camera is factory calibrated and for many purposes this calibration should be good enough. If you really want to, you could calibrate both IR cams as described in [StereoCalibration](http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration/Tutorials/StereoCalibration), however.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0